# SPContext.Current.Site.SystemAccount.UserToken is giving access denied

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Users who have permission to the sub site but not to the top level site are getting access denied error when I use **SPContext.Current.Site.SystemAccount.UserToken** in my web part added to the sub site. Only after I give them read acces to the top level site they are not getting access denied error.

Can anyone please let me know where am I going wrong. Thanks.

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/62193/16880 resolved my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a normal behavior of limited access to  **SPContext.Current.Site.SystemAccount.UserToken** for users with restricted privileges. Just image that the property **SystemAccount** is a member of site collection **SPContext.Current.Site** for which current user in sub site has no rights.

But if you wish to get **SPContext.Current.Site.SystemAccount.UserToken** anyway you can do it with [SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPriviliges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx)